# Date Formatting in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

everybody...
I was wondering how I could format the a date in the datepicker 'd de MM de yy' in stead of 'dd/MM/yy'.

(suppose the date is 21/01/2011 (in spanish) .. so:
$("#element").datepicker({
     dateFormat:'d de MM de yy'
});

It will output : 21 21e Enero 21e yy

The question is.. is there an escape character so I can format the date?
Thanks, sorry for my English, hope you guys understand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape any plain text characters:

```
$("#element").datepicker({ dateFormat:'d \\d\\e MM \\d\\e yy' });
```

You may also be able to escape plain text using single quotes:

```
$("#element").datepicker({ dateFormat:"d 'de' MM 'de' yy" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the datepicker on startup, then just use a class to attach it later. I've defined a datepicker like this:

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional["no"], {showStatus: true, defaultDate: +1, minDate: 1, maxDate: 365,  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", showOn: "both", buttonImage: "../images/shop/calendar.png", buttonImageOnly: true}));
```

Should be explained in the options/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for date format and year till the current year

```
$('#element').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1920:+nn",
        maxDate: 0
    });
```